# SSAS Tabular Model - Dealing with date and 30 minute time interval

Tags: time, filter, ssas-tabular, powerbi-datasource

I've created an SSAS Tabular Model in which I have two different tables, `AGENT` and `CHAT`, that I would like to be related in order to filter and group by `DATE` and a 30 minute time interval field called `INTERVAL` in a Power BI report hierarchy.

[image: SSAS Tabular Model]

Both tables are related to a `DATE` table with unique date values. In Power BI I have a table that contains measures from both tables but the filter does not work by interval but it does by date as they are related.

[image: PBI graphic interval problem]

How can I get through this being efficient in the model?

Answer (score 1):

The SSAS Tabular Model doesn't allow Many:Many relationships, I would never be able to join the `AGENT` and `CHAT` tables.

SOLUTION I found:

Create a view in the SQL Server Database that contains all the data from the `AGENT` and `CHAT` tables by using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Whenever a `NULL` value appeared in the `DATE` or in the `INTERVAL` column I selected the correspondent non-null value from either the `AGENT` or `CHAT` table. This was only possible thanks to both tables having the same values for the intervals.

Having the view I was able to filter all the data as needed.